# getJSON and looping with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I cleaned my code down to a very simple script and it drives me nuts, that it doesn't work.

The idea is to get a JSON string via Webservice and then display the data. Yes that seems to be a very simple thing...

The JSON string is valid:

```
[
{
    "FileName": "Test1",
    "GuestRating": 7.09,
    "ID": 1066113,
    "Image": "A110897780.jpg",
    "Latitude": 35.534599,
    "Longitude": 121.759896,
    "Name": "Test 1",
    "NumberOfReviews": 317,
    "Rate": 19.19,
    "StarRating": 4,
    "UpdatedDate": "2012-11-09T16:48:27.65",
    "UpdatedBy": "test"
},
{
    "FileName": "Test 2",
    "GuestRating": 8.03,
    "ID": 1066110,
    "Image": "A110563463.jpg",
    "Latitude": 31.432816,
    "Longitude": 122.53242,
    "Name": "Test 2",
    "NumberOfReviews": 164,
    "Rate": 27.92,
    "StarRating": 4,
    "UpdatedDate": "2012-04-26T10:46:34.403",
    "UpdatedBy": "test"
}
```

]

My javascript:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('api/hotels')
            .done(function (data) {
                alert(data)
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    alert('11111');
                    items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
                });
                alert('2222');

                $("<ul/>", {
                    "class": "my-new-list",
                    html: items.join("")
                }).appendTo("body");
            })
        .error(function () {
            alert('error');
        });
    });

</script>
```

It is mostly copied from the jQuery example on their website.
the first alert works and shows the JSON data.
then it just seems to die. no more alerts.
The Javascript console of chrome shows following statement:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1525' in
```

followed by my JSON string. I have no idea what that means.

Thanks to anyone with a hint!

Comment: looks like you have some problem... the value `data` seems to be of type string.... but since you are using getJSON I don't understand how it is happening... can you try `alert(typeof data)` before the `$.each()`

Comment: Arun is right on track. `data` seems to be a string. Could it be that the data you are actually getting is something like `"[...]"` (i.e. it quotes around the value)? That's the only way I could explain that behavior. Also the fact that you see "the object" when you call `alert(...)` indicates that it is a string. If it was an array of objects, you would see `[object Object], [object Object]`.

Comment: It could be that you need to make sure that the JSON content is indeed delivered with a contenttype header that is application/json. To see if it is indeed delivered with that header open the chrome dev-tools. Ctrl + Shift + J. Go to the Network tab and refresh or make sure your ajax call is made. It should show up in the list for you to examine the details. Also make sure that data is not of string type and if it is you can use JSON.parse instead of setting the contenttype.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson: If you call `$.getJSON`, then jQuery will treat the response as JSON, not matter the content type header.

Comment: @FelixKling Okay I regress. Just remeber having trouble with that using $.get but according to the specs you are right.

Answer (score 1):

With JSON that you have included `$.each(data, function (key, val) {` does not return `keys` like `FileName`. Why? because `each` iterates over the array and each time would return an index and a complete object.

```
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
    ...
```

Comment: @FelixKling in what has been posted, there is no `in` used. It might be jquery doing that and the cause could be treating an object as if it was text (not sure though).

Comment: To extend @MajidFouladpour answer here is the demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5Ds4P/